# Tricks / acitivities to make a toddler stay in one place for a while

Tags: toddler, activities

My 18MO toddler is very active. When she's not running, she's walking, and when she's not walking, she's picking things up, and otherwise she's climbing, sitting on stuff and standing up.

What tricks can you use or what activities can you come up with to make a toddler stay in one place for a longer while? Or at least be immersive enough to keep the child in one room in more or less the same place?

Comment: Do you think this might be better as a community wiki?

Comment: No idea, do as you wish:)

Comment: It's a bit more a of a "list" question than one which will end up with a definite "best" answer.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious ones which sometimes work:

- books
- sorters
- puzzles
- counting things
- a bowl of water and containers (outdoors and on warm/hot days only)

Comment: +1 for the water play.  You can also do a lot at the sink, standing on a stool, wearing a plastic apron.  - -  To get a few minutes' peace to be able to cook dinner, for example, you may put the child in the high chair with a strap, with a fun activity on the tray.  - -  Another trick is to hire a mother's helper, which is a child between the ages of 6 and 14, who can entertain the toddler while strapped into the high chair or stroller.  Give the mother's helper some hand puppets and they'll be off and running (figuratively speaking).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep you toddler engaged can be a few activities

1. Play Dough is one of the best activity for little one, where they can make creative things with that.
2. Paint in bags. Place some paint in a plastic zipper bag and seal the bag, then paste it or tape on a window and let your kid move the paint with the fingers.
3. Set up a pack and play and put books and stuffed animal in for your little one to play with.
4. Painting.
5. Coloring. Make you little one any images like animals, super heros, cars etc and tell to color those sheets with the crayons.
6. Blow a balloon and play tennis with that balloon.
7. Do some apple stamping on the paper.

These are the few activities that can keep your toddler busy.